Would like help with analog signal amplification circuit with several unknown capacitor values
This is a 10 GHz radar signal amplification circuit that I "reconstructed" by tracing the actual PCB. It is supposed to measure speed of objects like baseball, archery arrows, bb/pellets up to 1200 fps. My calculations are about 31 kHz where the low-cutoff should be (critical), and the high-cutoff is anywhere below around 500 Hz (not critical).
The signal from the sensor is about a 0-10-20 mV sine wave. The op am is 3.5 MHz. I did some calculations, and I believe this is a 10x first stage op-amp and a 100x second stage for a total of 1000x gain. After the second stage the DC is removed by C34 capacitor and only the AC(???) is passed on to the microcontroller.
The microcontroller (MCU) uses SAADC with max 200 kHz sampling. The amplified AC(??) signal goes in the AIN0 of the SAADC and a reference DC voltage of 2.4 V (VCC/2) goes into SAADC AIN1. Not sure what the ADC is set, and how it's configured. I believe the MCU pins have 10 kΩ internal resistance.
**Since the capacitors are in circuit, prefer not to remove them. Was able to measure some of them, but not certain about their valid values.  Could you help me figure the approximate value of the capacitor? Also, do you think I missed some other components?
Capacitors C10, C8, C28 look like power conditioners, so probably 1nF, 100 nF, 1 µF. I am primarily interested in C1 and C14 (350 pF??  35 pF?? or other values?). And the capacitors in the signal path like C6, C15 (5 µF ???), C34, C36 (35 pF???).**
EDIT 1:  Thanks for the good idea! Injected a 0.8V sine signal tone of 0.25 sec length in lieu of sensor signal and high-pass is 500 Hz and low-pass is @ 22 KHz. Was hard to determine the low-pass value, because there seems to be a wide band of inconsistent readings between 23 Khz to 26 Khz and above 26 KHz readings are not measurable. I expected @ 31 KHz for the low-pass, but 22 KHz is not a deal breaker and I expect that my methods are not the most accurate.
So based on these findings, using the inverting op amp model's high-pass and low-pass equations, I calculated the following potential values for the capacitors:
High-pass first stage op amp:
C6 capacitor = 3.18 nF
High-pass second stage op amp:
C15 capacitor = 318 pf
Low-pass first stage op amp:
C1 capacitor = 70 pf
Low-pass second stage op amp:
C14 capacitor = 7 pf
Please, let me know if you see any errors or wrong assumptions.


ADCs can measure DC voltage.If you are measuring AC voltage, is it RMS voltage?

@AmitM   Thank you for the input. Because of C34 I believe that the MCU's ADC is measuring AC voltage. I used a DC meter at C36 capacitor and was below 300mVDC with an active signal input. Then I switched to AC measurement and was jumping over 2.34 VAC with active signal input. Unfortunately, do not know how the MCU's ADC is setup.  But I know that the program uses FFT to identify the dominant frequency from the amplified sine wave signal that is about 50us to 3ms period long.

Can you disconnect the sensor input? If yes, inject a sine wave and plot the characteristics of the stages.

@AmitM your statement is kind of wrong. ADCs are used for any signal that's bandlimited sufficiently, or where only instantaneous values are important. So, DC, AC, and a lot of things that don't perfectly fit into either category.

You can measure AC voltage using a differential ADC.

@MarcusMüller  Yes, I can disconnect the sensor.  What should I look for when injecting a sine wave? I have an oscope, but as far as I know it only generates a 1KHZ square wave, Have a cheap frequency generator but only does square waves. Will look to setup an Arduino with a sine wave program, or maybe use my laptop's sound output port.

@AmitM  I believe that very likely this SAADC is setup as a differential ADC that has AC one one pin and DC on the other.  But I do not have access to the MCU's program, can only see the output value which is in the measured velocity.

If you can inject a 1 V sine wave, measure the amplitude after each stage. Use a scope to measure, a DMM will have frequency limitations. Use frequencies: 1 Hz, 2, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 200, 500, etc. Convert ratio to dB, plot on log freq scale.

Thanks for the suggestions!  I added an "edit" above with my findings.  Used an oscope.   The capacitor values I ended up calculating for this inverting two stage op amp seem low. But I checked my calculations and seem fine.  At the end, a 500 Hz high-pass and 31 KHz low-pass with the existing resistors values is what I am looking for.

@AmitM differential or not has nothing to do with it. You seem to have pretty fundamental misunderstandings about ADCs.

@Mattman944 and all.  I  added in my main post above the results of my findings and some calculations based on them. Do you see anything that may need to be investigated or if my values seem off?  Thank you.

Marcus Müller, in your private universe, perhaps yes.

You are assuming that the bandwidth of each stage is the same, this may or may not be true. You haven't shown any data or plots, so I can't verify your methods.

@Mattman944 I think I need to use a frequency measurement code instead of the FFT I am using now. I am new to FFT, and it also adds uncertainty as far as the accuracy of frequency cutoff readings.  Since I know the exact freq I am inputting, I will use a frequency counter code to measure it to verify the high-pass and low-pass.  Using the FFT may explain why I was getting funky values above 22 KHz, and changing sampling Freq and sampling rates also resulted in an entirely different reading for the same freq input at higher frequencies, nearing 1/2 sampling freq (nyquist).

I am not sure what you are doing with FFTs, you are making this too complicated. For each frequency input, measure the output of each op-amp with a scope. For the second stage, you will need to calculate the 2nd stage output divided by the first stage output. If this doesn't work out, you may need to lift the opamp pin on the output of the first stage so you can inject directly into the second stage.

Out of town a few days...will re-attack this when I return back home. Until then I am revisiting the frequency bandwidth parameters of the project and get a better handle on the related basics.
